# Visual Studio: Clean and rebuild with one macro

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I am trying to optimize my work with VS by creating some macros. Currently I have the following macros:

```
Public Sub ReleaseBuild()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Release")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
End Sub

Public Sub DebugBuild()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Debug")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
End Sub
```

What I want is to clean the solution before actually rebuilding it. What I did was:

```
Public Sub ReleaseBuild()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Release")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.CleanSolution")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
End Sub

Public Sub DebugBuild()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Debug")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.CleanSolution")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
End Sub
```

But I get the error bellow:

[alt text http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/2667/errorcb.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/2667/errorcb.png)

I believe clean has to be done first before rebuilding. I know this can be done by running two separate macros, but I actually want to achieve it with one click.

Best Regards,

Kiril

Comment: The Rebuild command already does a Clean first.

Comment: How do I mark your question as answer?

Answer (score 6):

Rebuild does not CLEAN solution first

I know that from experience when working with a lot of projects and when I add param to method in one project and call that method from second project with implementation of additional parametat *rebuild* often show error considering number of parametaes in that method!

use

```
DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean(True)
DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)
```

not

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.CleanSolution")
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
```