# Clean solution and rebuild solution in Visual studio by Single click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros

Trying to add external command **Clean + Rebuild** both in a single click.

Was not found the solution from this question: [Clean and build in one Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176630/visual-studio-clean-and-rebuild-with-one-macro)

doing the same as suggested in it, still not found the exact solution.

What i have tried is

**1.Make a Notepad file with Name command.exe, and add this code in it**

```
Public Sub ReleaseBuild()
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean(True)
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)    
End Sub

Public Sub DebugBuild()
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean(True)
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)
End Sub
```

**2. Then add a command in External Tools**

[image]

**3. Assign a shortcut to the Command**

As my External tool no is `4(By Index)`, i have add this command to **ExternalCommand4**

[image]

**And the error occurred when i hit the shortcut.**

[image]

Can anybody tell me where i am wrong??

Comment: Look up what a Rebuild does. It's a clean and build.

Comment: Why do you mean "clean + rebuild"? Rebuild itself is clean + build.

Comment: Did you just add text data into the command.exe contents?

Comment: but to add this command in the Tools, yes add the text in it

Comment: I suppose "The command is not a valid executable" is about trying to execute a text file as .exe

Comment: Firstly, as noted above, a rebuild is a clean and build in Visual Studio. Secondly, you cannot just rename a text file to a *.exe extension and thereby create an executable. You need to compile some code classes into an executable using VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message

[image]

because you are trying to execute command.exe file with text contents:

```
Public Sub ReleaseBuild()
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean(True)
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)    
End Sub

Public Sub DebugBuild()
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean(True)
   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)
End Sub
```

Just renaming text file into .exe doesn't make it executable. You are supposed to either *compile* it or use a *script engine*.